# C++: execute two tasks and kill the one which takes longer

Tags: c++, caching, process, kill

Let's suppose we have a generic task which doesn't produce any side-effect. Let's suppose we have a result caching (or memoization) mechanism, which avoid to perform our task for some previously seen input.

Let's suppose that this caching mechanism is potentially time expensive, and we want to avoid to waste time for cache misses.

My solution so far is: as soon as the system receives the input data, execute two different processes. The first one is the original task, as it would happen without the caching mechanism. The second one looks inside the cache structure. The first process which terminates, kills the other. This is obviously more expensive in terms of resources, but we guarantee that our system with this caching mechanism is **at most expensive as the original one**.

So, my question is: is it possible to implement this "kill the slower process" in C++, in any moment and given any task (without side-effects)?

PS: to guarantee the best possible performance, these two processes may be distributed in two different machines.

Comment: Are you using "process" in the general sense "some sequence of computations", or in the same sense as the OS "partitioned memory space in which code can run isolated from other processes except through OS-provided I/O APIs"?

Comment: not really clear what you have so far and what is missing. Everything following "My solution so far:" sounds already like a full solution

Comment: What is the expected duration of the task in question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @BenVoigt The second one

Comment: @tobi303 I don't know if given **any** kind of task assigned to a process it is possible to interrput/kill it in **any** moment in C++.

Comment: @Leon we are talking about any task, but it's supposed to be time expensive (order of hundreds of milliseconds, several seconds). Typical applications could be avoid image processing expensive tasks (like recognition).

Comment: @TobySpeight I didn't try any solution yet. I've seen many questions which are not based on a already defined solution and it's legit in Stackoverflow. Am I wrong?

Comment: It helps to have a skeleton of code around which to hang a precise answer.  Vague questions tend to attract vague answers, so the more you can give us, the better.  As it is, I'd suggest `fork()`ing two children; and `poll()`ing their output - when either replies with the answer, kill both children.  But I haven't tried it myself.